# Getting the color of a google glass

Tags: android, colors, google-glass

I am trying to find the information that can provide the information of the color.

Indeed, i wanna know the color in order to modify the user interface.

Is there a database (sqlite) or any other information where i can get this information ?

Comment: as a complement, i have tried to get info from the get prop command but no useful data...

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're going to have to try to restate your question. The way it is phrased currently makes absolutely no sense. What color are you talking about?

Comment: Hi alex,

I am talking about the color of the plastic housing of glass google.

I was thinking my request was understandable.

Any idea the color information ?

Comment: Oh, wow, you want to know what color the glass is programatically

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this. The only hardware traits that are typically stored would be the amount of RAM, amount of memory, processor, etc.

Aesthetic things such as color don't actually fit into there. First of all, Glass doesn't interact with its color at all, so it can't really run any test to detect that. Second of all, for the software to know what color the Glass was, Google would have to put a different version of the software onto each pair of Glass depending on the color that has that specific color in its traits.

I don't think there is a way to do this. I look around the Google Glass Explorer forums as well, and didn't find any possible solutions there.

Cool question though. I hope this helps. Good luck :)